# MVC4: Disable mobile views on certain controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got .cshtml and .Mobile.cshtml for all of my views. Is there a way to disable .Mobile.cshtml on certain controllers? For such controllers, I always want to use the normal views instead of mobile views.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you found any other solutions to this?

Comment: Sorry, I did not find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for sounding stupid.  But if you always want to use a normal view, just remove the mobile view from the project.

**Edit**

To force the browser to load the desktop view on a mobile device you will need to use the BrowserHelper [SetOverriddenBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.browserhelpers.setoverriddenbrowser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Within your action method you could do something like this

```
HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Desktop);
```

Try this link for more help http://blog.mirajavora.com/overriding-browser-capabilities-in-asp.net

Comment: Actually the mobile view in not present there but the Layout for mobile  view is present in shared folder. MVC loads the layout of mobile view and body of normal view. I want it to show the layout of normal view as well.

Comment: Thanks for that Colin. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Cookie is being created but no effect on the view.

Comment: As Colin said, I think I just deleted the mobile views for the controllers where I don't want them to appear